# Possible to change RSYSLOG_FileFormat timestamp output without changing conf file?

Tags: date, logging, awk, timestamp, rsyslog

I currently have a system with RSYSLOG_FileFormat enabled in rsyslog.conf. I am not allowed to change the system format, so I'm trying to find a workaround that will enable me to view the output to stdout of the log file ( /var/log/messages in this case) to the desired timestamp format mentioned below. The reason being it is much easier for me to quickly navigate log files that don't require as much precision. Suggestions are much appreciated!

example current output timestamp:

```
2020-12-17T19:05:34.118891+00:00
```

Desired output:

```
Dec 12 2020 19:05:34
```

Comment: I assume `Dec 17 2020 19:05:34` is correct?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank your input. My AWK-FU isnt really that great. I figured much that I had to incorporate awk. However, I have only used basic awk commands such as printing columns.

Comment: If `dec` is also ok for reading using the locale’s abbreviated month name: `awk -v FS="[T.]" '{print strftime("%b %m %Y %H:%M:%S", mktime(gensub(/[ :-]/," ","g",$1 " " $2)))}' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` and two arrays:

```
awk 'BEGIN{m[10]="Oct"; m[11]="Nov"; m[12]="Dec"}
     {
       # split first field from current row ("$1")
       # (here: "2020-12-17T19:05:34.118891+00:00") with
       # field separator "T", ".", and "-" in five parts
       # to array "array"
       split($1, array, "[T.-]")

       # rebuild first field from current row with elements of array "array"
       $1=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s", m[array[2]], array[3], array[1], array[4], $2)

       # output complete current row
       print
     }' /var/log/messages
```

As one line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{m[10]="Oct"; m[11]="Nov"; m[12]="Dec"} {split($1,array,"[T.-]"); $1=sprintf("%s %s %s %s %s", m[array[2]],array[3],array[1],array[4],$2); print}' /var/log/messages
```

Please complete yourself array `m`.

Comment: Can you break this down? I'm not all too sure what's going on in that awk expression. Ideally, I would like to manipulate this to show all the output for in the desired format Month-Day-Year HH-MM-SS. i noticed here this is using Dec and Nov specifically. Can this be applied to the entire log file without specifying months? I hope I am making sense.

Comment: @mondragonfx: I have added to my answer to make it clear. You would have to add the remaining 9 months.

Comment: when you say "Please complete yourself array m." are you referring to type the rest of the months such as m[01]="Jan"; m[02]="Feb" etc..